# Angular 6 - How to extract translation from typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, localization, internationalization, translation

I am using Angular 6 and I have setup handling of translations according to the documentation found here: https://angular.io/guide/i18n.

The problem is that the documentation does not explain how to get translations using typescript.

There is a similar question here: [Can I use Angular i18n to translate string literals in typescript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49124757/can-i-use-angular-i18n-to-translate-string-literals-in-typescript-code)

But i cannot use that answer since it relies on ngx-translate which will be deprecated once Angular catches up, see https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/495.

So using the Angular 6 i18n - how would i get the translated text using typescript based on for example an id?

Answer (score 0):

@Diemauerdk, the documentation not explain how get translations using typescript because this is not possible. A work-around can be has in several .ts the translations. That's

```
//file locale-us.ts
export const translation:any={
   greeting:"Hello World!",
   mainTitle:"The best Appliacion of the world"
}
//file locale-es.ts
export const translation:any={
   greeting:"¡Hola Mundo!",
   mainTitle:"la mejor aplicación del mundo"
}
```

In your .ts you can have a pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { translation } from '../../i18n/locale-us';


@Pipe({ name: 'translation' })
export class TranslationPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor() {}
    transform(value: string): string {
        return translation[value] || null;
    }
}
```

And you can use in a component where you inject the pipe in constructor some like

```
constructor(private translate: TranslationPipe){}
//And use like

alert(this.translate.transform('greeting'));
```

Then you can use the apart "fileReplacements" in angular.json. not show all the angular.json else where you must add the fileReplacement. You has a fe.g. of this if you download the i18n example of the documentation https://angular.io/guide/i18n#internationalization-i18n

```
  "configurations": {

   "production": {
        ...
    },
    "production-es": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }, //add this two lines
        {
          "replace": "src/i18n/locale-us.ts",
          "with": "src/i18n/locale-es.ts"
        }
      ],
      ...
      "outputPath": "dist/my-project-es/",
      "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.es.xlf",
      ...
    },
    "es": {
      //And add this too
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/i18n/locale-us.ts",
          "with": "src/i18n/locale-es.ts"
        }
      ],
      ...

     "outputPath": "dist/my-project-es/",
      "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.es.xlf",
      ...
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Eliseo, Thanks for the answer. We need to use the Angular 6 i18n and we cannot define our translation in a .ts file. We need a standard like xliff so a translator can work on it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48327401/angular-i18n-work-around-for-translations-in-code/50191658#50191658 ?

Comment: This solution seems more reasonable to me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54684087/134120