# Angular 10: Translate strings known to i18n in variables at runtime

Tags: angular, internationalization

is there a possibility to translate strings known to i18n in Angular 10 within the code by calling something like:

```
translate(myText);
```

where 'myText' is a variable, that contains a string, known to the i18n.

A simple example. I have this code in HTML:

```
<div i18n>This is a simple Test.</div>
```

And then I would like to do something like this in Code:

```
const transText = translate('This is a simple Test.');
```

The text in brackets is just for the example, it would not be in the code at compile time. In reality it would come from a string, that is passed to a custom html-element that cannot be marked with i18n or i18n-Attribute. Also it is not possible to mark it in code with $localize `...`.

The text will be exactly the same as defined with the i18n-Attribute or $localize.

One thing, that comes to my mind to solve this is to parse the languagefile, that i provide as a json structure at startup to the app, but for this i would need to know the id, that is generated for this text. Another idea, i got was to lookup the text in the original XLF-file, take that id and search for it in the translated structure.

But both versions are not very good and seem very problematic to me, since they depend upon not changing the way that i18n in Angular works. I would prefer to have an internal way to translate such a string.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NOT. You can has a "translate(texto)". Well, Always can call to an API. The more closer attempt I know is using [transcolo](https://netbasal.com/introducing-transloco-angular-internationalization-done-right-54710337630c) and there are some work-arounds. I don't know is the idea from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498997/angular-6-how-to-extract-translation-from-typescript/52505296#52505296) that has almost 2 years old, and [this another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48327401/angular-i18n-work-around-for-translations-in-code/52527048#52527048) can help you. With the pass of time, I improve a few the idea although really it's the same:

A component translation

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-translation',
  template: `<div *ngIf="!yet" style="display:'none'">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
            </div>`
})

export class AppTranslationComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChildren(AppTextComponent, { read: ElementRef }) divs: QueryList<ElementRef>;
  data: any
  yet: boolean = false;
  get(text: string, ...args: any[]) {
    if (!this.data)
      return "";
    let response = this.data[text];
    if (response && response.match(/\[.\]/))
      response.match(/\[.\]/g).forEach((l, i) => {
        response = response.replace(l, args[i])
      })
    return response
  }
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    if (this.divs.length) {
      this.data = {}
      this.divs.forEach(c => {
        this.data[c.nativeElement.id] = c.nativeElement.innerHTML
      })
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.yet = true;
      })
    }
  }
```

And a component text

```
@Component({
  selector: 'text',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class AppTextComponent { }
```

In any component:

```
<ng-translation>
  <text id="one1" i18n="@@component-one1">This is the one1</text>
  <text id="one2" i18n="@@component-one2">this is the one2 [0] greatting</text>
  <text id="one3" i18n="@@component-sum">The sum of [0] and [1] is [3]</text>
</ng-translation>

@ViewChild(AppTranslationComponent, { static: true }) t: any
```

And you can use

```
  const value=this.t.get('one1');
  const value2=this.t.get('one2','Peter');
```

Or in .html

```
  {{t.get('one3',2,3,5}}
```